# How to share functions between 2 node js server?

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 node js server running and each of them have their package.json files. I want to share function which is in "backend-node-express" folder to "backend-report-service". My folder structure like this:

```
backend-node-express/
├─ controllers/
│  ├─ analyticsController.js
├─ app.js
├─ server.js
├─ package.json
├─ DockerFile
backend-report-service/
├─ controllers/
│  ├─ reportController.js
├─ app.js
├─ server.js
├─ package.json
├─ DockerFile
```

I'm trying to import analyticsController to reportController by doing this:

```js
const analyticsController = require('../../backend-node-express/controllers/analyticsController');
```

But I'm getting `Error: Cannot find module '../../backend-node-express/controllers/analyticsController'`
When I ctrl+left click the path it opens the file. I also added ./ to the path and it did not work. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please provide more details.